# Time out error when executing Jest test with puppeteer

Tags: node.js, reactjs, testing, jestjs, puppeteer

have a small suite of tests based on Puppeteer with Jest, and I can't get rid of the following problem

```js
× test page header logo (5019ms)

  ● test page header logo

    Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.

      at node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queue_runner.js:72:21   
      at Timeout.callback [as _onTimeout] (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/Window.js:633:19)
```

### the test code

```js
test("test page header logo", async () => {

  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });

  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto("localhost:3000"); // our react app;

  const text = await page.$eval("a.brand-logo", (el) => el.innerHTML);

  expect(text).toEqual("Logo");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should `done` `test("test page header logo", async (done) => {` and run done function after last `expect expect(text).toEqual("Logo"); done();`

Answer (score 0):

The same issue happened to me and I solved it with a method called **waitFor**
which is on page instance.

```
test("test page header logo", async () => {

  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });

  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto("localhost:3000"); // our react app;
  // added waitFor method
  await page.waitFor('a.brand-logo');
  const text = await page.$eval("a.brand-logo", (el) => el.innerHTML);

  expect(text).toEqual("Logo");
});
```